# Magento 2 & Amasty Feed Extension - Missing Products

Tags: php, magento, magento2

We currently have a Magento 2 installation with minimal changes (pretty much still Luma). The most notable difference is we have created our own import module for importing products via XML.

This all seems to work fine and we can see our products on the frontend. However, in the automatically generated google feed (created by Amasty Feeds Extension), some/most of the product data is missing. Some of them also aren't visible in the back end of Magento. I'm at a loss. I can't tell if the problem lies with our own import module or Amasty's extension.

I've checked the configuration of the Amasty module, magento product info (stock, quantity, price, availability, visibility) and it all looks okay. The template we're using for the Amasty feed is below (based on the pre-installed templates);

```
    <g:id>{attribute="basic|sku" format="as_is" parent="no" modify=""}</g:id>
<title>{attribute="product|name" format="as_is" parent="no" modify="html_escape"}</title>
<description>{attribute="product|description" format="as_is" parent="no" modify="html_escape|length:500"}</description>
<g:product_type>{attribute="category|category" format="as_is" parent="no" modify="html_escape"}</g:product_type>
<link>{attribute="url|short" format="as_is" parent="no" modify=""}</link>
<g:image_link>{attribute="image|image" format="as_is" parent="no" modify=""}</g:image_link>
<g:condition>New</g:condition>
<availability>{attribute="inventory|is_in_stock" format="as_is" parent="no" modify="replace:1^In Stock|replace:0^Out of Stock"}</availability>
<price>{attribute="price|final_price" format="price" parent="no" modify=""}</price>
<g:brand>{attribute="product|manufacturer" format="as_is" parent="no" modify="html_escape"}</g:brand>
<g:google_product_category>{attribute="product|manufacturer" format="as_is" parent="no" modify="html_escape"}</g:google_product_category>
<g:tax>
 <g:country>UK</g:country>
 <g:rate>0</g:rate>
 <g:tax_ship>n</g:tax_ship>
</g:tax>
<g:shipping>
 <g:country>UK</g:country>
<g:price>{attribute="product|price" format="price" parent="no" modify=""}</g:price>
</g:shipping>
<g:identifier_exists>TRUE</g:identifier_exists>
<gtin>{attribute="product|ean" format="as_is" parent="no" modify="html_escape"}</gtin>
<g:mpn>{attribute="product|mpn" format="as_is" parent="no" modify="strip_tags"}</g:mpn>
```

There don't appear to be any errors relating to this in either the server or magento logs.

Comment: reduild cache ? deploy static content? magento is in dev mode?

Comment: @bxN5 Rebuilt, deployed, re-indexed and yep, it's in Dev Mode. Also not using flat tables.

Comment: Dont trust Amasty extensions. They have their worst code in their extensions. This is the feedback I got from Magento team..

Answer (score 0):

Amasty Feed extension gets the data on price, availability, etc. from product index. This means that your index should work properly for the feed to be generated correctly.

What is more, you should check for which products the info is missing. It may happen with disabled items as once they are disabled, Magento stops adding its attributes to the index. So the chances are high you haven’t used a filter to generate product feed for only enabled products.

If you still have questions, don’t hesitate to ask our support team https://amasty.com/contacts/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have indeed posted to the support team and they're looking in to it now. Unfortunately, these products are enabled and the indexes are okay (with the exception of Catalog Rules, separate issue)